# Winform show screen resolution

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm wondering is it possible for a winform display to find and display the current screen resolution that it is currently displayed on?

For example, if my screen is 1920 x 1080 it would show this in a label or a print line. Though the latter part is something I know how to do already.

Could someone please enlighten me to if it is possible for a winform to find this data please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [Screen class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8xzhd15.aspx)

```
 label1.Text = string.Format("Primary screen size = {0}x{1}", 
               Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 
               Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, c# and WinForms can get your current screen resolution, try this code

```
Rectangle resolution = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
int w = resolution.Width;
int h = resolution.Height;
```

Or you can try to show it as a label or as a messagebox

```
label1.Text = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width.ToString() + "x" + Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height.ToString();
```